# How can this "Jim Browning" YouTuber have access to all these scammers' PCs?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, system-compromise, trojan, scam

I've been watching these videos on YouTube about some British-sounding male (with millions of views) busting Indian scammers.

It is never explained how exactly he is able to do this, with him basically implying that he's some sort of Hollywood "hacker".

Even assuming that what he does is technically illegal, and thus "swept under the rug", how is this *technically* possible?

No person who scams people all day is going to run some EXE that he e-mails to them or however he does it. I don't get it. How can he have access to their computers when *they* (the scammers) need the victims to go to URLs and ignore all kinds of warnings and run EXEs?

His videos make me feel uneasy even though I've never scammed anyone in my life, or ever dreamt of doing so. I get the feeling that I'm missing something very important.

Comment: "No person who scams people all day is going to run some EXE that he e-mails to them" -- you are going to have to challenge that assumption

Comment: Without knowing how he does it, we can't tell you ... how he does it.

Comment: Sometimes the need to know has to be correlated with an actual purpose, not just to feed the eager to knowledge.

Comment: i would suggest the possibility that someone on YouTube might be fake and trying to collect views from entertainment.